# Error in implementing Microservices with Express.ts and Rabbit MQ

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, rabbitmq

Rabbit mq file

```js
import express from "express";
import amqplib, {
  Message
} from "amqplib";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world Express.js");
});

const connect = async() => {
  try {
    const connection = await amqplib.connect("amqp://localhost");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    app.post("/publish", async(req, res) => {
      const message = req.body;
      const queue = 'myQueue';
      try {
        await channel.assertQueue(queue, {
          durable: false
        });
        await channel.sendToQueue(queue, Buffer.from(message));
        res.send('Message published to Rabbit MQ');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Rabbit MQ Error");
      }
    });
    app.get("/consume", async(req, res) => {
      const queue = 'myQueue';
      try {
        await channel.assertQueue(queue, {
          durable: false
        });
        channel.consume((queue), (message) => {
          console.log('Received Message', message ? .content.toString());
          const msg = message as Message;
          channel.ack(msg);
        }, {
          noAck: false
        })
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Server is having some problem in Acknowledgement");
      }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

connect();
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Service 1

```js
import express from "express";
import amqplib, { Message } from "amqplib";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello world Express.js");
});

const connect = async () => {
  try {
    const connection = await amqplib.connect("amqp://localhost");
    const channel = await connection.createChannel();
    app.post("/publish", async (req, res) => {
      const message = req.body;
      const queue =  'myQueue';
      try{
        await channel.assertQueue(queue,{durable:false});
        await channel.sendToQueue(queue,Buffer.from(message));
        res.send('Message published to Rabbit MQ');
      }catch(error){
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).send("Rabbit MQ Error");
      }
    });
    app.get("/consume",async(req,res)=>{
        const queue = 'myQueue';
        try{
            await channel.assertQueue(queue,{durable:false});
            channel.consume((queue),(message)=>{
                console.log('Received Message',message?.content.toString());
                const msg = message as Message;
                channel.ack(msg);
            },{noAck:false})
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            res.status(500).send("Server is having some problem in Acknowledgement");
        }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

connect();
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

Service 2

```js
import express from 'express';
import axios from 'axios';

const app = express();
const port = 4000;
const serviceRegistryURL = 'http://localhost:5000'; 

app.get('/',async(req,res)=>{
try{
    const service3url = await getServiceUrl('service3');
    if(!service3url){
        throw new Error('Service2 not found in the registry')
    }
    const response = await axios.get(`${service3url}`);
    res.send(`Response from service 3 is ${response.data}`);

}catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
}
})

async function getServiceUrl(serviceName:string):Promise<string|null>{
    try{
        const response  = await axios.get(`${serviceRegistryURL}/services/${serviceName}`);
        return response.data.url;
    }catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("server is listening for Service 2 port 4000");
})
```

Service 3

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port  = 5001;
const serviceRegistryURL = 'http://localhost:5000';


app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("Hellow wolrd from service 3");
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log("Server is listening for service 3");
})
```

Service Registry

```js
import express from 'express';

const app = express();
const port = 5000;
const services:{[name:string]:string}={};

app.get('/services/:name',(req,res)=>{
    const {name} = req.params;
    const url = services[name];
    if(url){
        res.send({name,url});
    }else{
        res.status(404).send(`Service Name is found ${name}`);
    }
})

app.post('/services/:name',express.json(),(req,res)=>{
    const {name} = req.params;
    const {url} = req.body;
    services[name] = url;
     console.log(`Service ${name} registered at ${url}`);
     res.send(`Service  ${name} registered sucessfully`);
})

app.listen(port,()=>{
    console.log(`Server Registery listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
})
```

In this implementation, I am trying to implement a micro services architecture using Rabbit mq, but I was not able to (I did manage to setup the rabbit mq server successfully).

But after implementing it when the time comes to query, I get an error like

[image]

which is nothing but the error message which I am logging out in service1.ts